# Find Files in Path and Read all Files starts with same pattern

Tags: python, file, path

1.) How can I connect path and read all files in directory ?, one by one,
Becouse I need some data from files and now its working only for one file.

2.)The pattern (name) always starts with IS.T.BCA. (like in the example below).
So now Its working only for one file.

Thank you.

```
with open('IS.T.BCA.SomethingMore','r') as f:
new=open('new.txt','w')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use globbing like below:

```
import glob

# reads all IS.T.BCA.* files into a list
files=glob.glob('IS.T.BCA.*')

# iterate over that list
for file in files:
    with open('IS.T.BCA.SomethingMore','r') as f:
        new=open('new.txt','w')
        ...
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this . where "IS.T.BCA.*" is the regex pattern for the file you are expecting

```
import re
import os
pattern = re.compile("IS.T.BCA.*")
path = '.'
for f in os.listdir(path):
  if os.path.isfile(path+os.sep+f):
    fobj = open(path+os.sep+f,'r')
    ...
    ...
```